# Conditional Formatting Range of Data

Tags: excel, vlookup, conditional-formatting

I have two tables of data in an excel spreadsheet. There are 10 columns of data in the first table that have values.

**Image of the tables**

[image: Spreadsheet Image]

There are actually four but I am essentially trying to conditionally format the data in the tables that are on the right side if the values do not equal the value in the tables on the left side and I cannot figure out how to do it all at once. I certainly don't want to do each cell one by one. Also, in case it matters, the table on the bottom right uses a formula that divide the value from the cells of the table on the left by 25.4 to convert the values to exact millimeters. All of the values in the top tables are manually typed in.

I am not very good at advanced formulas in excel and I would assume that you would have to use a vlookup which I do not know how to do.

Comment: Did you try `MATCH()` function?

Comment: Select `O4:X24`, then Conditional Formatting - Use formula... : `<>C4`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select O4:Z24 on your sheet.

Click `Home` tab and select `Conditional Formatting`

In the dropdown `Highlight Cell Rules`  and `More Rules...`

In the New Formatting Rule window select Format only cells that contain

In the middle dropdown select `not equal to`, and in the right type `=C4`

Click on `Format` and select the desired formatting. (e.g. Fill -> choose a color), click OK, and OK.

The cells which not equal to the corresponding value in the left table will be colored.

This can be applied for the bottom right table too, with changing the ranges.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I just tried that and it highlighted the entire table on the right except O4 because it matches the value in C4 because the formula is only looking at that C4 for comparison. If I change any of the other cells in the table on the right to 95 then it is no longer highlighted.

Comment: @laughlin Be sure that there are no $ sign in =C4

Comment: Well that is the stupidest thing ever :D I removed the dollar signs that it automatically put in and that worked like a charm. Thank you!